# Too many }'s. \end{figure}

Tags: floats, errors, compiling

I am writing my thesis that works just fine but whenever I try to add in figure it gives me an error saying there are **too many }'s. \end{figure}**

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (medical) {\textbf{Medical}};
\node [block3, right of=medical, node distance=7cm ] (math) {\textbf{Mathematics}};
\node [block2, below of=medical, node distance=2.5cm] (brain) {Brain structure and its functions};
\node [block2, below of=brain, node distance=2.5cm] (epilepsy) {Epilepsy and data gathering from patients};
\node [block2, below of=epilepsy, node distance=2.5cm] (flat) {Flattening of EEG data};
\node [block4, below of=math, node distance=3.2cm ] (decompose) {Decomposition of matrices};
\node [block4, below of=decompose, node distance=3.2cm ] (distribution) {DNumber Theory};
\node [block5, below of=flat,right of=flat, node distance=3.5cm ] (JC) {Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of EEG signals during epileptic seizure};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (medical) -- (brain);
\path [line] (brain) -- (epilepsy);
\path [line] (epilepsy) -- (flat);
\path [line] (math) -- (decompose);
\path [line] (decompose) -- (distribution);
\path [line] (flat) -|  (JC);
\path [line] (distribution) -|  (JC);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An overview of the research}
\label{fig:overview}
\end{figure}
```

My current packages are

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis, enumerate, amsfonts, amsmath, graphicx, longtable, qtree, etoolbox, amssymb, lscape, rotating, array, pst-node, tikz, lipsum, blindtext, pdflscape}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@xfloat=\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
    \latex@xfloat #1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}
    \@normalsize\normalsize
    \normalsize
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  %I want to put figure here
  \begin{figure}

  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can someone show me what did I do wrong?

The UTMthesis.sty code is as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The package UTMthesis.sty will produce the output    %
% of a thesis according to UTM Thesis Manual,          %     
% School of Graduate Studies, 2007.                    %
% Yusof Yaacob, Department of Mathematical Sciences,             %
% Faculty of Science,  Universiti Teknologi Malaysia   %
% 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia                          %
% e-mail: yusofby@utm.my                               %
% 24 December 2009                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX cod for chapter header
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ 
      \centering  
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \normalsize 
           \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
       \par\nobreak
              \vskip 1.4\baselineskip 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize     
         \bfseries #1\par\nobreak 
       \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
  {\parindent \z@  
    \centering  
    \normalfont 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize 
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
         \vskip 1.4\baselineskip  
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for layout
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.2cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.7cm}   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.46cm} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
   \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm} %  \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
   %\setlength{\headheight}{2mm}
    %\setlength{\headsep}{10.175mm}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for 1.5 spacing
   %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  indentation
   \setlength\parindent{.5in}
   \usepackage{indentfirst} %1st line indented after section...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for space between paragraph
  \makeatletter
    %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip \@plus 3ex
                %  \@minus 2.0ex}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip \@plus .01ex
                  \@minus .01ex}
   \makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for no hyphenation and right justified
    \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy
    \raggedbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command to get rid of default running head
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  page number 
%  \makeatletter
%    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
%    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill\textrm{\thepage}}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
%    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }
%   \makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

 %For section font
 % \usepackage{sectsty} 
  %  \chapterfont{\centering\normalsize\uppercase}
  %  \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
   % \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
   % \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for REFERENCES name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change vertical space in section and subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%      % the name
  {1}             % the level
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm}    %{0.5cm}    % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%   % the name
  {2}             % the leve2
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm} %{0.5cm}        % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change horizontal space in section and subsection
% for times romans
   \renewcommand{\thesection} % space between sect. etc.
     {\thechapter.\arabic{section}\hspace{.12in}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection} 
       {\thesection\hspace{-.3cm}.\arabic{subsection} \hspace{-.135cm}} 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for  TocLoFT
  \usepackage{tocloft}
    %\cftsetrmarg{2.75cm} %    
     \cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} %  
       \cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm} 
       %\cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
    \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % get rid of dots
%Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}        % off tocname
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{.8cm}      % chapter indent
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.3cm}      % section indent
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3.25cm}  % subsection indent
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.45cm}  % chp number width
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
%-------------------------------------------------------------  
%List of Table
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  %\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{} % off lotname
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.015cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.1cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
 %List of Figure
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % off lofname
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-.1cm}      % figure indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for bold caption
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   % caption parameter
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\,\,\,\,\,} #2} %%%%%
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % caption parameter
           {#1\,\,\,\,\,}  #2\par  % caption parameter
       \else                                   % caption parameter
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  % caption parameter
   \fi}                                            % caption parameter
\makeatother   
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{paralist} %refine list item
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx} % .eps graphic
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape
%-------------------------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{times}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Theorem-Like-Environment
\usepackage{theorem}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter] }
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Solution}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please post a minimal complete document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and exhibits the problem. In its current form, this question is hard to answer because it has numerous loose ends.

Comment: The document edited @Schrödinger'scat.

Comment: I do not have `UTMThesis.sty`. If I remove it, the lower code runs through. So if you have problems with the lower code as is, chances are the culprit is `UTMThesis.sty`,

Comment: I added the code for UTMthesis.sty. Can you take a look at what's wrong with it that makes me cannot use tikz package @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: You may find the UTMthesis.sty in the link provided. https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d789a3db16b1500015cd04a @Schrödinger'scat